# Adding a script tag and script to window.open

Tags: javascript, window.open, scorm, tin-can-api

In my LMS I have the code below used to display a SCORM player window:

```
window.open("@Model.SCORMStartPage", "SCORM", "width=1140,height=760,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0");
```

I now need to adapt this to play a TIN CAN course and I need a way to add the script tag and the javascript below into the window.open window

```
<script type="text/javascript" src= "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tincan.js")"></script>

var tincan = new TinCan
(
    {
        recordStores: [
            {
                endpoint: "https://cloud.scorm.com/tc/V4FF9VBCSY/",
                username: "email",
                password: "password"
            }
        ]
    }
);
```

Comment: It is not a video, it is a tin can captivate created course, I need to find a way of adding a script tag and the javascript to the new window being opened

Comment: I don't think you can append things to new windows opened up. C# can't do it because it onlyh works on the page you've created. The window isn't part of what you've created. I don't think JavaScript can do it because it has no control on how the window will be rendered.

Comment: .appendChild is probably what I am looking for nevermind